# Will a sidecar scale on a K8s Deployment?

Tags: kubernetes, istio-sidecar, sidecar

Has anyone practical experience with this scenario? Given an increase in load and concurrency for a service, will the sidecars scale as well? Can the limits be defined?

Comment: You can set the resource limits per container, to scale up. But usually you would prefer to scale out, by creating more replicas (pods of the same app).

Comment: If you have a Deployment, and a HorizontalPodAutoscaler, and the Pod template has a sidecar (either in the Deployment or injected by a mutating admission controller), then every copy of the Pod will have its own sidecar as the HPA scales up and down.